# Lattice Diamond does not allow me to open Active-HDL, it shows me this message

Tags: verilog, fpga, lattice-diamond, active-hdl

(FLEXlm error = -5) No such feature exists.

Please run the License Information of the Help menu to verify Aldec license environment settings or define new license.
For ordering information contact sales@aldec.com

I have downloaded the free version of Diamonds, but I'm unable to run the simulator Active-HDL.

Comment: Do you expect to be able to run Active-HDL with the free version. I had a look at Lattice's website and it wasn't clear to be. Do you have a licence for Synplify?

Comment: [Aldec Active-HDL Lattice Edition II](http://www.latticesemi.com/en/Products/DesignSoftwareAndIP/FPGAandLDS/LatticeDiamond/DiamondOverview.aspx) *When using Lattice Diamond with the free license, simulation is enabled for Active-HDL Web Edition II which offers many of the same features with less capacity.* Have you requested the [Diamond Software Free License](http://www.latticesemi.com/en/Products/DesignSoftwareAndIP/FPGAandLDS/LatticeDiamond.aspx#_FD13D8A25CBB47BD83F143E5B55DBC75) or are you trying to invoke the wrong edition?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a licensing issue for a commercial product; the question should be directed to the vendor, or asked on a vendor forum.

Comment: @user1155120 yes I requested and obtained the free license, that's why am asking what's wrong, I should be running the simulator without problems.

Answer (score 0):

By default Diamond toolchain will only allow you to run Lattice from inside ICEcube. To run it from command line (or in scripts) you'll need to set some environment variables. Here's what worked for me on Windows (with my version of Lattice toolchain):

```
$ source ./set_vars.sh $ICE_ROOT
$ $SIM syn/sim.do
```

(links to scripts: [set_vars.sh](https://github.com/yugr/primogen/blob/master/boards/icestick/set_vars.sh), [sim.do](https://github.com/yugr/primogen/blob/master/boards/icestick/syn/sim.do)).